# multidimentional ArrayList[][], is it even possible?

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array, arraylist

so I have a task to make a field for a game. I can have numerous items on every field and the size of the field is chosen by the user. My question is how can I do that. I tried with an array ArrayList, but every time I try to add a value to it, I get a NullPointException. How can I solve this problem?

This is what I've come up with. 'TypeInfo' is an array String(the problem isn't in it, I checked), but I get the exception at its line:

```
List<String[]>[][] items = new ArrayList[x][y];
itemBoard[0][1].add(typeInfo);
```

Comment: are `itmes` and `itemBoard` supposed to be the same same variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, `itemBoard[0][1]` isn't initialized to anything.  `NullPointerException` means something is `null`, so find the `null` thing and make sure it's not `null`.

```
List[][] items = new ArrayList[x][y];
itemBoard[0][1] = new ArrayList<>(); //java 7 shortcut
itemBoard[0][1].add(typeInfo);
```